# How can I force a line break in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, line-breaking

I'm writing a pretty long document, and at some point this happened with the table of contents:

> [image]

I would like to be able to force a line break between 'complex' and 'space', either directly or by imposing suitable limits on line lengths or the separation between the lines and the numbers, or any such relevant lengths.

A minimal working example is below,

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % load a font with all the characters
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{lipsum}


%%% Headers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{Electron dynamics in complex space and complex time}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents  
\setcounter{page}{100}
\chapter{Quantum orbits as trajectories through complex time and complex space}
\lipsum[1-16]

\end{document}
```

including the headers in use in the document; obviously all of the non-lipsum packages are necessary in the larger document. How can I fix this ugliness?

Comment: But you *don't* want this happening in the header. What do you use to create your header?

Comment: @Werner See edited post with the headers in use.

Comment: @E.P. Why not using `\chapter[Quantum orbits as trajectories]{Quantum orbits .... long title}`??? Such long titles appear in the headers too, unless you would use `memoir` where you can specify the header title too, in addition to the ToC entry and the heading title

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The title fits perfectly in the header, and I would quite like to keep the longer title in the table of contents as the information you've chopped off does matter ;-). It is perfectly possible for the chapter title to have a line break in the TOC, which you get e.g. by removing the `fontenc` package. What I want works, it's just LaTeX trying to bully me into thinking it knows better, even though it demonstrably knows better than what it is saying now that it thinks it knows better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could specify your chapter using

```
\chapter[Quantum orbits as trajectories through complex time and complex \texorpdfstring{\\}{} space]% ToC/Header
  {Quantum orbits as trajectories through complex time and complex space}% Document
% Correct header setup to not insert a line break
\markboth{\thechapter.\ Quantum orbits as trajectories through complex time and complex space}{}
```

The optional argument to `\chapter` sets the ToC *and* header entries. So we replicate the usual `\chaptermark` to correct for inserting a line-break inside the header.

Alternatively, increase the `p`age `num`ber `width` inside the ToC and/or set the alignment of `chap`ter-related entries to include a `\raggedright` alignment:

```
\cftsetpnumwidth{3em}% Default is 1.55em
\cftchapfont{\bfseries\raggedright}% Default is \bfseries
```

[image]

---

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides the option of explicitly setting all three possibilities via

```
\chapter[<toc>][<head>]{<title>}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to configure the toc with a larger space for the page numbers and setting the titles ragged right like. The op is already using tocloft

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it raises a hyperref warning (token \\ not allowed) which I'd rather not have without good reason. And, as daleif said, I'm already using `tocloft`, which *should* provide enough customizability to do what I need. (Unfortunately, the `tocloft` documentation is, as usual, beautifully typeset and completely impenetrable to anyone but the package maintainer.)

Comment: @E.P.: I've added the use of `\texorpdfstring` to distinguish between TeX and PDF-related content. That takes care of the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) warning (due to the PDF bookmarks). I'll update my answer to include a [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) adjustment as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably plenty good. For future googlers it's probably best to include a `tocloft` fix, though.