# Overflow the world in the my article

Tags: line-breaking

I have a problem with the overflow of the world, and example

### 1

[image]

### 2

[image]

### 3

[image]
For resolve this problem I found two solutions, they are:

- \newline
- rewrite the sentences with the new words to resolve the overflow problem.

Exist another problem to resolve this problem?

This is an example minimal reproducible

```
\documentclass[11pt]{toptesi}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Bitcoin. OP\_0 funge da segnaposto per un bug nell’implementazione di OP\_CHECKMULTISIG}
\subsection{P2MS}
\label{sec:p2msbitcoin}
Gli script {\it pay-to-multisignature} definiscono una condizione M:N (molti a molti) dove M è il numero minimo di firme necessarie per verificare lo script di blocco e N è il numero totale di chiavi pubbliche.
Il numero massimo di combinazioni ammesse per uno script P2MS è 15:15, ma solo le combinazioni rientranti nell’intervallo 3:3 sono considerate standard; tutte le restanti combinazioni verranno considerate come non standard.
Un esempio di script P2MS 2:3 è il seguente:


In questo esempio OP\_0 funge da segnaposto per un bug nell’imleme.. OP\_CHECKMULTISIG, il cui unico scopo è quello di aggirare un bug che è diventato accidentalmente una regola di consenso.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can introduce manual breakpoints in that non-breaking word. But we are only able to help you if you provide a minimal code example of how you created this.

Comment: you can allow the word to hyphenate eg `\CHECK\-SEQUENCE\-VERIFY`  or force a line break before it, allowing the previous line to be short, or force a line break before it, justifying the line so allowing white space to stretch,  or re-write the text, or use a smaller font, or use a wider text block on the page or .....

Comment: For this use, which appears to be a TOC (with page numbers), it would be reasonable to have a ragged-right "paragraph", with the uppercase command text on a new line, and the page number at the end of the second line.  But it's difficult to help without knowing how this was produced, hence the request for a compilable code example that can be used to experiment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have introduced the only example to representing the my problem, I won't know the alternative to fix this problem. I can't reproduce the problem with a minimal example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you give me an example to applying the hyphenate solution? ps: I can't reproduce the problem with a minimal example, this is a specific problem of my project

Comment: This must be reproducible with a minimal example. You just need a section heading which is too long for the ToC and ends in a word TeX can't hyphenate.

Comment: as crf says you could of course make a minimal example, you just need a document with one `\section`  with a long title, a `\tableofcontents` and nothing much else.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have created the minimal example, I have the problem overflow also in the text. Sorry if in the previous post I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328439/how-can-i-force-a-line-break-in-the-table-of-contents Also the hyphenation works as well. Wouldnt That solve your problem?

Comment: If the world overflows, you need to build a large wooden boat, known as an ark.

Comment: @IanThompson but make room for the animals!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert hyphens.  `\-` as suggested in the comments.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{toptesi}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Bitcoin. OP\_0 funge da segnaposto per un bug nell’implementazione di OP\_CHECK\-MULTISIG}
\subsection{P2MS}
\label{sec:p2msbitcoin}
Gli script {\it pay-to-multisignature} definiscono una condizione M:N (molti a molti) dove M è il numero minimo di firme necessarie per verificare lo script di blocco e N è il numero totale di chiavi pubbliche.
Il numero massimo di combinazioni ammesse per uno script P2MS è 15:15, ma solo le combinazioni rientranti nell’intervallo 3:3 sono considerate standard; tutte le restanti combinazioni verranno considerate come non standard.
Un esempio di script P2MS 2:3 è il seguente:


In questo esempio OP\_0 funge da segnaposto per un bug nell’imleme.. OP\_CHECK\-MULTI\-SIG, il cui unico scopo è quello di aggirare un bug che è diventato accidentalmente una regola di consenso.

 \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]